# Previnir usuario de digitar o token manualmente pelo browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Existe uma maneira de previnir que um usuário tenha digitado manualmente o `access_token` pelo browser?

Por exemplo, se eu coloco uma key com o nome `access_token` direto pelo browser, e digito um value qualquer, eu consigo entrar em uma rota "protegida".

Basicamente, eu faço verificações sempre que o usuário entra em uma rota. Também uso o interceptors do axios, caso o token for inválido ele joga o usuário pra tela de login e remove o `access_token` do localStorage. Porém, se ele digitar algo qualquer, manualmente, ele conseguirá mesmo que por um segundo visualizar o conteudo de dentro da rota, até a requisição do servidor ser feita e entao ele ser mandado pra tela de login.

De certa forma, eu estou tratando desse jeito:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');

    if (token) {
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    if (auth.getters.isLoggedIn && to.name === 'login') {
        next('/');
    } else {
        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
            if (auth.getters.isLoggedIn) {
                axios.interceptors.response.use(response => response, error => {
                    const status = error.response ? error.response.status : null
                    if (status === 401) {
                        auth.commit('logout')
                        next('/login')
                    }

                    return Promise.reject(error);
                });
                next()
                return
            }
            next('/login')
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: "Prever" ou "prevenir"? "Prever" é impossível, pq vc não sabe o que o usuário vai fazer antes dele fazê-lo.

Comment: Isso, rs. Troquei as bolas!

Comment: Tenta colocar aquele next acima do return dentro do interceptor em um if status === 200